# How force a jquery ui draggable to restart after mouseup called

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a draggable div ***#box*** able to move inside a larger one ***#dashboard*** and I can see it only through another div, smaller than dashboard the ***#window***

This is the order:
 `<div id=’dashboard’> <div id=’window’ > <div id=’box’ ></div> </div> </div>`

What I’m looking  for is to recrate an auto-scolling movement when the ***#box*** reaches the border of the ***#window***.
Therefore on window mouseleave (while dragging) I bind a setInterval which start to move the ***#dashboard*** in the opposite direction.

I have noticed that the draggable ***#box*** stop moving, because the user stop moving the mouse when exits the window (while he keep it pressed) expecting the movement to continue by itself.

So I have to move force the draggable ***#box*** position with a movement opposite to the ***#dashboard*** to render it apparently stand still and close to the border.

This create a distance between the ***#box*** and the mouse position (which is outside the ***#window***) and when the mouse starts moving again it will drag the ***#box*** from this position (awful!).

To avoid this I decided to force draggable to stop when the mouse leaves the ***#window*** tiggering mouseup (I read this on the forum and it works).

And now I need a way to restrart the drag when the mouse re-enter the ***#window***.
How can I do?

---

**Update:**

I try to explain the situation with the images:
[image] Here start the drag moving the box outside the window
[image] to scroll the window it have to start move backwards (setInterval() is called)
[image] moving the window causes the box to move back itself because it has absolute position
[image] therefore I have to reposition the box close to the window border, but this causes a distance between the box and the mouse pointer which is outside the window
[image] And now the problem: when the mouse is moved again and drag event is trigged it "remembers" the distance with the box and magically moves it without touching...

---

**Update 2:**

I have created a jsFiddle to show all the code: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UPFNU/)
To test is just move the ***#box*** outside the ***#window*** on the right,
the ***#dashboard*** will start movig backwards (to stop it just came back inside the window).
Unfortunately two bad things happen:

1. it will be created a distance between the mouse pointer and the box,
   and when you'll move back to the window the box will be dragged from
   this distance
2. if you keep moving the mouse outside the window the box will start
   flashing between its "*drag position*" and its "*border corrected*"
   position.

the second issue could be avoided adding this `$("#box").trigger("mouseup");` before the setInterval being called, but it requires a kind of opposite function like `$("#box").trigger("mousedown");` when the mouse re-enters the window to trigger the drag once again, hence the title of my question.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle?  Also you might want to experiment using the `helper` option with a callback and making a manual clone that is positioned outside of the window.

Comment: I've tried to save a jsFiddle for you but I can't figure out how to set the JQuery UI library (I was able to set JQuery framework only). Therefore I decided to upload some images to better explain the situation.

Comment: On second Update you can find the link to the jsFiddle, now I've learned how to connect JQuery UI also.

Answer (score 0):

I have temporary resolved (because I still hope in a better solution) following “*Nal*” suggestion:

1. When the ***#box*** start drag it is replaced by a ***#clone***
   (`display: none` on box)
2. On drag the ***#clone*** takes the `ui.position` of the ***#box*** if
   it is inside the visible ***#window*** and remains to the border if
   the mouse pointer goes out
3. Stopping the drag the ***#box*** gets ***#clone***’s `css('left')` and
   reappears (`display: block`) while the ***#clone*** is removed.